# Eisenstein Plane

Tags: vector-spaces, modules

Suppose I plotted points of the Eisenstein integers $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\right]$, where the point $a+b\omega$ was the point $(a,b)$. How could I describe this plane in the language of vector spaces and modules? In terms of vector spaces, we only care about integer multiples of points, but $\mathbb{Z}$ isn't a field, so we couldn't really call $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ as a "$\mathbb{Z}$-vector space". In terms of modules, it seems like we could call $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, but $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ isn't an Abelian group... Could someone help me out here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh I think I figured it out; It can just be thought of as a Q-vector space...

Comment: What if I was working with some linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$? R^2 is a R-vector space with basis {(1,0}, {0,1}), so how would we call Z[w]?

Comment: Yes but suppose I had to consider lines in the eisenstein plane and points that weren't algebraic integers. Would it be called $\mathbb{Q}[\omega]$?

Comment: Why do you say it is not an Abelian group? Are you dealing with a weird form of non-commutative "addition?"

Comment: Elements aren't invertible...

Comment: What do you mean? You can both add and subtract, no problem.

Comment: @mixedmath Oh ooops.... wait so if I had T: R^2 -> Z[w] I could say Z[w] is a Z-module with basis {1, (-1+sqrt(-3))/2}?

Comment: Yep, you sure could.